# PHPMailer error loading page

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Form submission</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    require("PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");
    $mail = new PHPMailer(); 
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // send via SMTP
    IsSMTP(); // send via SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->Username = "mygmail@gmail.com"; // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = "MY_PASSWORD_GOES_HERE"; // SMTP password
    $webmaster_email = "username@doamin.com"; //Reply to this email ID
    $email="some1@mail.com"; // Recipients email ID
    $name="name"; // Recipient's name
    $mail->From = $webmaster_email;
    $mail->FromName = "Webmaster";
    $mail->AddAddress($email,$name);
    $mail->AddReplyTo($webmaster_email,"Webmaster");
    $mail->Subject = "This is the subject";
    $mail->Body = "Hi"

if(!$mail->Send()){
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else{
    echo "Message has been sent";
}
?>
```

This is my php script to send an email. It is pretty straightforward and taken from the PHPMailer homepage. I am trying to serve this from an Apache server that serves my webpage.
When I try to access the script I get the error: failed to load page.

Is there anything wrong with the php code here? I have modified my php.ini file also, so everything seems to be like it has to, but it does not work.

Comment: There's a missing `;` in your `$mail->Body` line. You should enable `display_errors` and set `error_reporting` to `-1` on your development machine.

Comment: What is the name of this file and why are you adding HTML tags on top in php code.

Comment: Syntax error. Look in your server logs for the error details, or enable the display errors flag to see what's going on. Also, if you use a decent IDE/text editor with syntax highlighting, it would show you the problem instantly.